# Can I cut down a quick release skewer?

Tags: trainer, quick-release, skewer

I recently purchased a Conquer brand trainer - I have learned a lot after buying this thing - but I didn't know what quick release skewers were before I purchased the trainer.

I've got a skewer that came with the trainer and after replacing the wheel to take a quick release, I fit the skewer onto the wheel and frame. After doing this, the skewer sticks out about 5/8in beyond the cap. This will not work in the trainer.

**Can I cut this down with a saw? Should I expect to have trouble in the future if I do this?**

I'm new to the realm of bicycling, so thanks for any help with this.

[image: skewer]

[https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qugte.jpg < image url](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qugte.jpg)

Comment: The skewer does fit the trainer when not screwed tightly on the wheel and frame. 
Here's an album of more photos: http://imgur.com/a/Z0MsT#0
Let me know if there's anything in particular you want a photo of.

My thought is that the skewer is meant for a wider axle/fork configuration. I'm not sure what the standard lengths are for axles and quick releases, but this is an older Schwinn road bike that didn't originally have a quick release.

Comment: Get a fitting skewer. They're not that expensive, about $10-15 for a standard issue.

Comment: You can cut the skewer, like any bolt.  You should find two standard steel nuts that fit the threads, thread them on, lock them against each other, then use them to guide you saw cut.  Once the cutting is done, unthread the nuts (helps clear the threads) and then dress the end with a fine file.  (Will never be as nice as a stock skewer, however.)

Comment: For old bikes, provided theres enough threading, you're going to have to cut the skewer since finding shorter skewers is getting trickier now.

Comment: Are you sure that the "nut" on the skewer is not bottoming out? Make sure you have at least 2-3 threads on the inside edge.

Comment: I'm with @Carel. Skewers are cheap enough that it's not worth the trouble of cutting it.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in fact you should cut it down because it's both a safety hazard (easy to gouge your ankles on an exposed bolt) as well as maintenance issue (it's easy to bend the exposed axle bolt and thus make it very difficult to unscrew the QR nut).

There are two ways to cut it, the first is on the bike and the second is off the bike.

On the bike:

1. Keep the wheel on the bike and use a hacksaw to gently cut through the exposed bolt. If you don't want to scratch your QR nut, you can protect it with some electrical tape.
2. After you cut the bolt off unscrew the QR nut, this will clean the threads. Use a file to clean up the end of the bolt as it will have sharp jaggies.

Off the bike:

1. Before taking it off the wheel, use a magic marker to mark on the bolt where it meets the face of the nut.
2. Unscrew the nut and remove the axle bolt from the wheel and put it in a vice.
3. Screw the QR nut back on (or use equivalent size real nuts) so that you can use it to chase the threads.
4. Cut the bolt at the right place using a hacksaw or dremel
5. File down the jaggies.
6. Use the previously screwed-on nuts to chase the threads.

Success!

Answer (score 2):

You can cut the skewer, but be sure to leave enough thread on there to keep the nut on when the QR is opened enough to take it off your bike (without having to remove the nut).

Don't forget to file the sharp cut edge smooth afterwards.